# Ranking pcollection elements

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Google DataFlow Java SDK 2.2.0. Use case as follows:

PCollection pEmployees: employees and corresponding department name. may contain up to 10 million elements.

PCollection pDepartments: department name and number of elements to be published per department. will contain few hundred elements.

task: Collect elements from pEmployees as per the department-wise number for all departments from pDepartments. This will be a big collection (up to a few hundred thousand elements or few GBs).

We cannot user Top transform here as it would work one at a time on pEmployee, whereas we have multiple departments and that too, in a PCollection. We can assign a row number to each of the elements from pEmployees, join it with pDepartments and filter the records where row_number > target number from pDepartments. This will require a global ranking.

Question: how can we assign rank/row numbers to the elements in a pcollection?.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to select a different number of employees from each department? Within a department, should the selection be arbitrary, or is it e.g. "top N highest-paid employees within the department"?

Comment: Yes, there would be different number of employees required to be taken for each department. For now the use case doesn't require ordered selection within the department, but having that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very close to the `Sample` transform, but not quite, because it applies the same threshold to all keys when used as `.perKey()`. Generally, Beam currently doesn't support per-key combines with different combine function parameters.

I'd recommend to emulate it by using `CoGroupByKey` to join `pEmployees` and `pDepartments` and obtain tuples (`CoGbkResult`) containing department name, N = number of elements, and all employees in that department. Then simply iterate through the employees and emit the first N and discard the rest.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach, but after `CoGroupByKey` some of the tuples may be large in size due to the number of employees in each department. If we process it in a `ParDo`, it may result into a skewed pipeline. Will this be recommended for production?

Comment: I think with a few million elements distributed (even if unevenly) over a few hundred keys there's nothing to concern about. I'd recommend to try it and see if the performance is not enough and this is the bottleneck. If so, I can recommend some alternative but much more complex approaches.

Comment: Note that the elements of joined collections with a common key don't need to fit in memory, even within a single key.

Comment: Thanks! is there any documentation available around this functionality?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? CoGroupByKey has javadoc.

Comment: I meant to ask about how beam processes large joined collections without having to fit the data for single key within memory. The documentation on the beam website does not have such details.

Comment: This is specific to a particular runner. I suppose you're using Dataflow; the details of Dataflow implementation are proprietary and change depending on configuration (there's several implementations of GroupByKey), you can read about one of them at https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/07/life-of-a-cloud-dataflow-service-based-shuffle